# In continous wavelet transform, all wavelets must have the same energy regardless of their scales,why?

Tags: image-processing, signal-analysis, digital-communications, wavelet

In Continuous Wavelet Transform (CWT) To achieve energy normalization and to ensure that all wavelets have the same energy regardless of their scales, each wavelet is divided by the square root of the the scale S.

Comment: It's only one of the normalization schemes, and a very poor one for most purposes - see under "L2 norm" [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/86069/50076). Contrary to its name, it does _not_ energy norm the transform in sense of [conserving input's energy](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/86182/50076).

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon, Why don't you write it as an answer?